# Woocommerce Paypal Fee calculated right but shown wrong

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce and offer paying with paypal for an extra fee of 0,90 cents plus 7% taxes. So it is 97 cents in total for every order which is payed with paypal. Now it is like this: When somebody pays with paypal the total sum is calculated absolutley correct with the taxes and everything, but the final listing in the confirmation mail and in my backend shows a completly random cents amount in the paypal fee field. Although the sum ist correct. I absolutley can not explain that. I tried two different ways to implement the fee. first I tried with the function woocommerce offers, second I tried with the plugin "woocommerce additional product fee for checkout pro". With both, it is the same result. Has anybody any idea what's the point here? 
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Fee is reflected in transaction details. Or, in IPN information. You can also call GetTransactionDetails API to get txn details with Fee. Also, you can download txn report from your PayPal account to see each txn details with Fee. Except for those methods, like txn information wrongly reflected in Magneto back end, PayPal cannot cover it. Instead, you are requested to contact Magneto or upgrade your current version of Magneto to see the new result.

Comment: hey there! thank you very much but i have no problem with paypal, since paypal just gets the full amount from my system. the failure is just in the appearance of the order details. the calculation is absolutley right, but it shows amounts for a paypal fee to my costumers in their order confirmations mails and in my backend which are completely randomly generated, althought, as i said, the total amount, is calculated how i want it to... i absolutely have no idea where this bug comes from..and by the way.. i use woocommerce!